# How can I reduce background width and reducing the div width

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, jsx

So, I want to keep the same size box with the same borders
however I do not want to color the whole background. I just want to color the few pixels in the center of it to make a red line in the middle of the box.
I can achieve that by creating another div element but I want to use one element to do both.
is it possible?

```
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 120px 30px 0px 30px;

  height: 140px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 0.2rem rgba(172, 255, 47, 0.565) solid;
```

this is what it looks like now [image]
I want to keep the same box size with those borders and instead of the hole box red. I want just a line in the center, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I used CSS pseudo element to insert the red box and then used css `transform` to position the box in the center. Does this solution meet your requirements ?

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 120px 30px 0px 30px;
  height: 140px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 0.2rem rgba(172, 255, 47, 0.565) solid;
}

.container::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  transform: translate(200px, 70px);
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited the wrong answer and it won't let me change it back. All I did was comment out the css margin.

Answer (score 0):

OK you want a red line in the middle of an absolutely positioned box with no additional html. You can use a background image (linear gradient) for that.

```css
.box {
border: 0.2rem rgba(172, 255, 47, 0.565) solid;
height: 140px;
/*margin: 120px 30px 0px 30px; this isn't necessary for the demo*/
position: absolute;
width: 400px;

background-image: linear-gradient(red, red);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position-y: center;
background-size: 100% 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```